# C++11/14/17 : template class pointer as template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Is it possible to declare a template function using a template class pointer?  Something like this :

```
template <typename FirstType, typename ... TypesRemaining>
class MyClass
{
  // ...
};

template <int n, template <typename FirstType, typename ... TypesRemaining> typename MyClass<FirstType, TypesRemaining...>::*ptr> myFunction() { 
  // ...
}
```

Is it possible to use 'using' to declare the pointer type? Something like this :

```
template <typename FirstType, typename ... TypesRemaining>
class MyClass
{
  // ...
};

template<typename FirstType, typename ... TypesRemaining>
using ptrMyClass = MyClass<FirstType, TypesRemaining...>*;

template <int n, template <typename FirstType, typename ... TypesRemaining> typename ptrMyClass<FirstType, TypesRemaining...> ptr> myFunction() { 
  // ...
}
```

Comment: What's the problem if you're trying to do this?

Comment: All the code above do not compile. I cannot figure how to do the right syntax to achieve something equivalent to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (compiles fine with clang, gives ICE with gcc):

```
template <typename FirstType, typename... TypesRemaining>
class MyClass
{
  // ...
};

template<int n, auto ptr> class
myFunction_impl;

template
<
    int n
,   typename FirstType
,   typename... TypesRemaining
,   MyClass<FirstType, TypesRemaining...> * ptr
> class
myFunction_impl<n, ptr>
{
    public: static void
    impl(void)
    {
        //  ...
    }
};

template<int n, auto ptr> auto
myFunction(void)
{
    return(myFunction_impl<n, ptr>::impl());
}

int main()
{
    myFunction<0, static_cast<MyClass<int, int, int> *>(nullptr)>();
    return 0;
}
```

[Online compiler link](https://godbolt.org/g/LnsHDc)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I forgot to say that I'm stuck with Visual Studio (2017 at least). I tried to compile your code and it doesn't work with VS. I got a message for the myFunction_impl class that the template declaration is "unrecognizable template declaration/definition" (I suspect that the parameter pack is not at the end). Also, I would like to better understand your solution. Why do you need to have an intermediate class for implementation? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Unfortunately VS does not have proper support for latest standards yet. Intermediate class implementation allows to define a partial specialization deducing  `FirstType` and `TypesRemaining` which is not possible for functions. If you don't really need them then intermediate class is not needed.